# Intermittent BindingExpression path error when changing tabs

Tags: wpf, binding, tabcontrol

I am working on a project that has a Tab Control some of its items have their `Content` set to an instance of an object and a `ContentTemplate` set as below

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AxisSetupTab">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding .[OpMode].Int }" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

This works great except when changing away from that tab to a tab with a different template I get the following error

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''ListBox' (Name='logListBox')'. BindingExpression:Path=.[OpMode].Int; DataItem='ListBox' (Name='logListBox'); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Curiously I get a slightly different error depending on what tab I switch to the `ListBox` and 'name' reflect the root element of whatever tab I switch to.

Since it works do I just need to live with the error or is there something that can be done about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are getting the error because the `DataContext` for the selected tab is changing dynamically.. and once the tab changes, the `DataContext` is no longer there.

To get rid of it, you can simply just add a `FallbackValue` as follows:

```
     <StackPanel>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <PriorityBinding FallbackValue="{x:Null}">
                <Binding Path=".[OpMode].Int" />
            </PriorityBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: There are a number of other elements in the stack panel, I cut down my template for clarity purposes, will give your solution a try

Comment: Sorry but that does not seem to have a noticeable effect

Comment: Are you still getting the Binding Error?

Comment: Still getting the exact same error as in the question